# Ошибка компиляции при использовании std::remove

Tags: c++

Пишу на плюсах в Xcode. Для удаления пробелов в строке использую:

```
lastZero.erase(remove( lastZero.begin(), lastZero.end(), ::isspace), lastZero.end());
```

Компиляция кода, запуск и выполнение приложения происходят отлично. Закидываю код на сайт задачи (которую выполняю), отмечаю "C++11 4.8.2 - GNU C++ Compiler with options: -lm -lcrypt -O2 -std=c++11 -pipe", компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
code.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
code.cpp:235:71: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’
         lastZero.erase( remove( lastZero.begin(), lastZero.end(), ' ' ), lastZero.end() );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вижу как минимум одно отличие: `::isspace` в Xcode и `' '` в сообщении об ошибке gcc. Может быть, была скопирована старая версия исходников?

[Важно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c#comment238112_83468), чтобы `::isspace` использовался с `std::remove_if`, а не `std::isspace` чтобы компиляция прошла успешно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // remove_if

int main() {
  std::string string("S P A C E S");
  std::cout << string << std::endl;

  string.erase(std::remove_if(string.begin(), string.end(), ::isspace),
           string.end());

  std::cout << string << std::endl;
}
```

[`v.erase( std::remove_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), is_x), std::end(v) );`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) идиома по удалению элементов из последовательности [работает](http://ideone.com/Hwes8L).

Осторожно: если строка содержит символы вне ascii, то [поведение `::isspace` не определено, если char тип имеет знак в данной реализации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c/83538#comment17753548_83538).

Comment: Да. То я менял на ::isspace. Та же ошибка. Есть ли какой-то аналог, чтобы одной строчкой кода удалить пробелы?

Comment: я только что проверил [код на ideone, он работает с c++11](http://ideone.com/RxP0L3). Можешь полный, но минимальный пример, который демострирует проблему, добавить к вопросу?

Comment: @iSerg: Вы пишете `remove`, а надо `remove_if`. То есть если `isspace`, то `remove_if`, а если `' '`,то `remove`.

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо.