# Почему find не находит пробелы в строке?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, stl

Пытаюсь сосчитать количество пробелов в строке, но через find выводит количество всех символов, а не пробелов. Почему и какая есть альтернатива?

```
for(int d=0;d<=s1.length();d++){
   if(s1.find(' ')){
    spaces++;
   }
}
```

Comment: А почему у вас переменная `d` не используется внутри цикла?

Comment: Осталось от старого кода, вопрос не в этом

Comment: Чем идиоматическое `for (size_t i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) if (s1[i] == '  ') spaces++;` вам не угодило?

Comment: Откуда взялось предположение, что "find не находит пробелы в строке"?

Comment: Если строка начинается с пробела, выведется 0, а не число символов  в строке..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала у вас задан неверный диапазон цикла

```
for(int d=0;d<=s1.length();d++){
             ^^^
```

Правильно было бы написать

```
for ( std::string::size_type d = 0; d < s1.length(); d++ ){
                                     ^^^
```

То, что делает ваш цикл, это подсчитывает количество символов в строке (если только строка не содержит пробел в самом начале), так как в этом случае условие

```
if(s1.find(' ')){
```

всегда будет истинно.

Вы могли бы записать цикл следующим образом

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++ )
{
    if ( s1[i] == ' ' /* || s1[i] == '\t' */ ) ++spaces;
}
```

Или если вы непременно хотите использовать функцию-член класса `find`, то

```
for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
      ( pos = s1.find( ' ', pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
      ++pos )
{
    spaces++;
}
```

Либо вы можете использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::count`

```
spaces = std::count( s1.begin(), s1.end(), ' ' );
```

Либо вы можете также подсчитывать и другие пробельные символы, как, например, символ табуляции, используя стандартный алгоритм `std::count_if` и стандартную C функцию `isspace`.

```
spaces = std::count_if( s1.begin(), s1.end(), ::isspace );
```

Для этого вам, естественно, помимо прочих заголовков нужно включить заголовки

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
```

Более корректно будет написать

```
spaces = std::count_if( s1.begin(), s1.end(), 
                        []( char c ) { return ::isspace( ( unsigned char )c ); } );
```

так как тип `char` может вести себя как `signed char`, и в этом случае если среди символов строки могут встречаться символы с отрицательными значениями кодов, то следует делать приведение к типу `unsigned char` при вызове `isspace`.

Comment: С маленьким уточнением: если строка будет начинаться с пробела, то `if(s1.find(' ')){` будет ложно.

Comment: @Harry Да, так как не сравнивается результат вызова find с std::string::npos

Comment: передать char, значение которого непредставимо как unsigned char и не  EOF, в ::isspace()  это undefined behavior. [ссылки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359790/23044)

Comment: @jfs Да, лучше использовать лямбда выражение с непосредственным вызовом фугкции в этом случае.

Answer (score 6):

Используйте возможности стандартной библиотеки. В данном случае, вам нужен [std::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>

    int main() {
        std::string str = "a b c";
        std::cout<<std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ')<<'\n';
    }
```

http://ideone.com/ZR8B6l

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int d=0;d<=s1.length();d++){  // Число итераций, на один больше числа символов
   if(s1.find(' ')){              // Вообще-то, проверяется сравнение с string::npos
    spaces++;                     // Увеличить значение
   }
}
```

По сути у вас код такой:
Увеличить `spaces` на число символов в строке плюс один, если пробел не на первом месте...

То, что вы хотите (поиск в цикле с помощью `find`), делается так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s = "jbcsdbl sdjkbhjskdfb sdfjkbjskdlfb sdfjkh  sdjkhjk";
    int spaces = 0;
    for(size_t pos = s.find(' '); pos != string::npos; pos = s.find(' ',pos+1))
        spaces++;
    cout << spaces << endl;
}
```