# Удаление одинаковых идущих подряд строк из матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы

Помоги, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку в коде. Нужно чтобы функция оставляла в матрице только уникальные строки. 
Например:
Вход 
0 0 0
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 1 0

Выход 
0 0 0 
0 1 0

Код:

```
int** RowCheck(int **m, int row, int col) {
    int similar;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int k = i+1; k < row; k++) {
            similar = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (m[i][j] == m[k][j]) { similar++; }
                cout << similar<<endl;
                if (similar == col) {
                    delete[] m[k];
                    for (int l = k; l < row; l++) {
                        m[l] = m[l + 1];
                    }
                    row-=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так, если уж не хотите использовать `vector`:

```
// Возвращает число строк
int RowCheck(int **m, int row, int col)
{
    int rowTo = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        bool isIn = false;
        for (int k = i+1; k < row; k++)
        {
            bool theSame = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
                if (m[i][j] != m[k][j])
                {
                    theSame = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (theSame)
            {
                isIn = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isIn && (rowTo != i))
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
                m[rowTo][j] = m[i][j];
            rowTo++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = rowTo; i < row; ++i)
    {
        delete[] m[i];
    }
    return rowTo;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int ** m = new int*[4];
    m[0] = new int[3]{0,0,0};
    m[1] = new int[3]{0,0,0};
    m[2] = new int[3]{0,0,0};
    m[3] = new int[3]{0,1,0};

    int rows = RowCheck(m,4,3);

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
    {
        for(int c =  0; c < 3; ++c) cout << m[r][c] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да обращайтесь :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать следующий подход. Сначала в начало матрицы переписываются уникальные строки. Затем создается новый массив равный числу уникальных строк, и в него переписываются указатели на уникальные сроки из исходной матрицы. Затем в исходной матрице удаляются все массивы после уникальных, и, наконец, исходная созданная уникальная матрица, то есть указатель, присваивается исходной матрице, то есть указателю на исходную матрицу.

Вы можете сократить число циклов. если будете использовать стандартные алгоритмы. Так алгоритм `std::equal` можно использовать для сравнения двух строк. Алгоритм `std::copy` используется для копирования строк. Алгоритм `std::for_each` можно использовать для удаления всех строк исходной матрицы, расположенных после уникальных строк.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая реализует описанный подход

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

size_t unique_rows( int ** &a, size_t m, size_t n )
{
    size_t k = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j < k && not std::equal( a[i], a[i] + n, a[j] ) ) j++;

        if ( j == k )
        {
            if ( k != i )
            {
                std::copy( a[i], a[i] + n, a[k] );
            }
            ++k;
        }
    }

    if ( k != m )
    {
        int **tmp = new int *[k];

        std::copy( a, a + k, tmp );
        std::for_each( a + k, a + m, std::default_delete<int[]>() );

        delete [] a;

        a = tmp;
    }

    return k;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t m = 4;
    size_t n = 3;

    int **a = new int *[m];

    a[0] = new int[n] { 0, 0, 0 };
    a[1] = new int[n] { 0, 0, 0 };
    a[2] = new int[n] { 0, 0, 0 };
    a[3] = new int[n] { 0, 1, 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    m = unique_rows( a, m, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::for_each( a, a + m, std::default_delete<int[]>() );
    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 1 0 

0 0 0 
0 1 0
```

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что если человек не использует стандартный контейнер, то и стандартные алгоритмы ему ни к чему...

Comment: @Harry Когда-то надо их начинать использовать и расширять свои познания в языке.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы удалить идущие подряд повторения строк в матрице, можно использовать простой алгоритм:

1. если текущая строка не равна последней записанной, то
   записать её в результат
2. повторять, пока все строки не закончатся. Вернуть указатель за последний
   элемент в результате

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template<class It>
It remove_same_adjacent_rows(It first, It last)
{
  if (first == last) // no rows
    return first;

  It d_first = first++; // keep the first row
  for ( ; first != last; ++first) {
    if (!std::equal(std::begin(*first), std::end(*first), std::begin(*d_first))) {
      // the current row is not equal to the last copied row; copy it
      std::copy(std::begin(*first), std::end(*first), std::begin(*++d_first));
    }
  }
  return ++d_first; // point after the last copied row
}
```

Пример:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int m[][3] = {
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0},
  };
  auto last_row = remove_same_adjacent_rows(m, m + sizeof(m)/sizeof(*m));

  // print the result
  for (decltype(last_row) row = m; row != last_row; ++row) {
    for (auto&& x : *row) std::cout << x << ' '; // print row
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Результат:

```cpp
$ g++ -std=c++11 *.cc && ./a.out
0 0 0 
0 1 0
```

---

`remove_same_adjacent_rows()` ведёт себя похоже на [`std::remove_if()`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). [Пример использования со стандартными контейнерами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/359788/23044). `remove_same_adjacent_rows()` работает без изменений и если матрица представлена как vector из vector:

```cpp
// 4x3 matrix
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(4, std::vector<int>(3));
matrix[3][1] = 1;
print_matrix(matrix);
std::cout << std::string(60, ' ') << std::endl;  // <hr/>
matrix.erase(remove_same_adjacent_rows(matrix.begin(), matrix.end()),
             matrix.end());
print_matrix(matrix);
```

где `print_matrix()` это просто:

```cpp
template<class C>
void print_matrix(const C& matrix)
{
  for (auto&& v : matrix) {
    for (auto&& x : v)
      std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Результат:

```cpp
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 1 0 

0 0 0 
0 1 0
```

Код использует стандартную [erase-remove идиому](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).