# Передача статического двумерного массива в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Понимаю, что тема уже заезжена до дыр, но пока носом не ткнут не пойму,вообщем выбивает ошибку, что n необъявленна, пытался объвялять ее в качестве глобальной но все-равно выдает ошибку, не понимаю, почему при работе с одномерным массивом все работает, а при двумерном нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int Sort(int [][n], int);

int main() {

        cout<<"Введите размерность квадратной матрици"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        cout<<endl;
    int array[n][n];

srand(time(NULL));

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)

    {
        array[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 100-40;
    }
}   
cout<<"Неотсортированная матрица"<<endl;
int row=n;
int col=n;
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
     {
            cout << array[i][j] << "  ";
     }
     cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;

Sort(array,n);
cout<<"Матрица с макс."<<endl;
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
    cout<<array[i][j];
    }
}
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
///////////////////////////////////
int Sortr(int array[][n], int n){
int iMax,tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        iMax = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            if (array[i][iMax] < array[i][j])
                iMax = j;

        if (iMax != n - 1 - i)
        {
            tmp = array[i][n - 1 - i];
            array[i][n - 1 - i] = array[i][iMax];
            array[i][iMax] = tmp;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout<<array[i][j]<<"  ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот [пример кода, где статический 2D массив `m`  в функцию передаётся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654095/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, имя `n` действительно нигде не определено. Во-вторых, язык C++ не поддерживает массивы переменной длины. Поэтому с самого начала

```
int Sort(int [][n], int);

int main() {

        cout<<"Введите размерность квадратной матрици"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        cout<<endl;
    int array[n][n];
    // ...
```

весь этот код является некорректным.

Либо вам следует использовать стандартный класс `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, либо значение "колонок" в двумерном массиве должно быть константной времени компиляции, а сам массив следует распределять динамически. И только число "строк" в массиве можно запрашивать у пользователя.